# How to obtain HttpContext (or AccessToken) for WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(token, action) from Blazor Server with IIS

Tags: iis, blazor

I am using the following quite successfully in MVC .NET Core hosted on IIS and in my development environment (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().AccessToken works fine with IISExpress in Development)

```
 public void RunImpersonated(HttpContext context, Action action)
        {
            // When running in IIS Express AccessToken(context) returns "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGIN"

            SafeAccessTokenHandle token;

            if (_env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                token = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().AccessToken;
            }
            else
            {
                token = AccessToken(context);
            }

            WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(token, action);
        }
```

I now want to do something similar with Blazor Server but I am struggling to get an HttpContext to pass into this method when the code is running on my IIS production server.

I have tried injecting IHttpContextAccessor and calling its .HttpContext but it always returns null and I'm not sure I should be doing that in Blazor anyhow.

In Startup.Configure I have:

```
          app.UseAuthorization();
          app.UseAuthentication();
```

In Startup.ConfigureServices I have:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
 services.AddAuthorization();
```

In IIS the site is set with WindowsAuthentication = Enabled, Anonymous = Disabled.
Ultimately I want to make a call to SQL using DatabaseConnection.SsisIntegratedSecurity and want to make that call as the current windows authenticated user (not the AppPool user but using the credentials coming from the browser).

Comment: Take a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64530246/why-ihttpcontextaccessor-always-get-null-ip-in-blazor-server-side

Comment: This worked great for the IP address, I've posted my code there, but when I saved the AccessToken in a simlar way, when I came to use it I received "Safe handle has been closed" errors.

Answer (score 0):

The Access Token can be obtained on any .razor page as follows:

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

.
.
.
  
 var token = ((WindowsIdentity) AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User.Identity).AccessToken;
```

allowing, on IIS:

```
ImpersonationHelper.RunImpersonated(token,
            () =>
            {
                // for example
                SsisJobs.StartJob(jobName);
            }
            );
```

```
  public class ImpersonationHelper : IImpersonationHelper
    {

.
.
.
      public void RunImpersonated(SafeAccessTokenHandle accessToken, Action action)
        {
            WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(accessToken, action);
        }
```